# fourth-order Runge-Kutta method producing values for $f(x)=\int_0^x e^{-t^2}$ (confusing answer key)

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, runge-kutta-methods

> Describe how the fourth-order Runge-Kutta method can beused to produce a table of values for the function
>
> $$f(x)=\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\ \mathsf dx$$
>
> at $100$ equally spaced points in the unit interval.

The answer is a little confusing and not full so would someone please explain the answer?
Answer:
Find an appropriate initial-value problem whose solution is f. Solve df =e^{−x^2}, f(0)=0.

Comment: do you mean $$\frac{d f(x)}{dx}=e^{-x^2}$$?

Comment: What more do you want out of the answer? You apply the Runge-Kutta method to the IVP and that produces the table of values for the function. It didn't ask you to actually apply the Runge-Kutta method and generate the values; just describe the method.

Comment: sorry yes i meant that; and i don't understand how you can describe it without applying the method?

Comment: I think, since they give you the problem in terms of an integral, the process they want described is how you can take the derivative and transform the intergral equation into a differential equation with initial value, which is accessible to runge kutta.